# get input value using Jquery Ajax without clicking and server

Tags: jquery, ajax

I met a problem. I know how to use jQuery selector to get input value and then update the information after clicking the button. But could I real-time update the following information when users input the value into the form and also the picture will change immediately via jQuery Ajax without clicking and server?

[image: desired output]

The detail please refer to the picture.
T T

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you didn't provide the actual HTML driving this interface I will attempt to answer you using attributes intended to be intuitive.

Realtime update of the title:

```
$('#title').keyUp(function(){
        $('.imageTitle').text($(this).val());
    });
```

Assuming that the radio buttons have an image path data attribute:

```
$('#animal').change(function(){
        $('.animalImage').attr('src', $(this).data('imgPath'));
    });
```

And then the description works much like the title:

```
$('#description').keyUp(function(){
        $('.description').text($(this).val());
    });
```

The magic here is using jQuery's event handling instead of waiting to press a button. Have fun!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. Do you know how to use JacaScript object window.localStorage to local store the data?

Comment: I mean, after user clicking the 'save' button, the values of the input elements should be saved in the local storage so that when the page is reloaded, ''the states of the page" can be restored(including values of the input elements, the image of the selected animal, the values in<div id title> and <div id =description>.

Comment: Build a JSON string to save on a localstorage attribute. On page load, try to read it and write values into elements with jQuery. Too much to really put in comments here.

Comment: Dear bro, I just posted another problem about this issue. If you have time, hope you could help me. XD Thanks.